# cocos2d score not resetting after game over

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

The score is not resetting right at all,I am trying to make a high score counter where every time you passed previous high score it will update.However, the score just keep going up without resetting even after game over I want the high score to be up until it is surpassed. I tried resetting the score in the game over layer but no good it would seem.

gameover .m

```
   CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];    
     _score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];           


 _oldScore = -1;
  self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 50)        alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
_scoreLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width - _scoreLabel.contentSize.width,    _scoreLabel.contentSize.height);
 _scoreLabel.color = ccc3(255,0,0);
  [self addChild:_scoreLabel z:1];         


   if (_score > _oldScore) {

_oldScore = _score;

[_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score%d", _score]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_oldScore forKey:@"score"];
```

. m hello world  file (the game file)

```
         CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];    
     _score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];           


 _oldScore = -1;
  self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 50)        alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
_scoreLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width - _scoreLabel.contentSize.width,    _scoreLabel.contentSize.height);
 _scoreLabel.color = ccc3(255,0,0);
  [self addChild:_scoreLabel z:1];         


   if (_score > _oldScore) {

_oldScore = _score;

[_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score%d", _score]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_oldScore forKey:@"score"];


_score =0;
```

the score however just keeps going up. I want the high score to stay until it surpassed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// get the previous highscore
  _previousScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];         
// get the current score from wherever you want
  int _currentScore???   
// check, if the current score is higher than the old
  if (_currentScore > _previousScore) {
// save the _currentScore in the userdefaults 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_currentScore forKey:@"score"];
// now update you label with _currentScore
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, there is only on problem left, the previous high score won't stay up. any suggestions?

Comment: yes the old highscore will be overridden. Use NSUserDefaults with another key to store the previous highscore.